# Необходимо нормализовать строку убрав все дополнительные символы возле слов. python

Tags: python

Есть такая строка:

```
\"X\" >'Y'> I  \t> 1Z2
```

Нужно чтобы на выходе получилась такая:

```
X > Y > I > 1Z2
```

У меня получается только без пробелов вообще:

```
s = str(input())
new_s = ''
for i in s:
    if i not in '!\"$%&\\\'*+,-./:;<=?[\\\]^`{|}~\\t\\n\\x0b\\x0c\\r' and i != ' ':
        new_s += i
print(new_s)
```

Comment: Что конкретно надо убрать или что надо оставить? Символы `',",\t`? Ещё что-то? Приведите полный список

Comment: Стоп, а почему на выходе у вас пробелы вокруг `Y`? Надо заменить на пробелы этот символ?

Comment: нужно убрать символы !"$%&\'*+,-./:;<=?[\\]^`{|}~\t\n\x0b\x0c\r. и да, вокруг '>' пробелы остаются и если есть лишний знак '>', то он тоже убирается

Comment: @EgorChernishov, можете привести больше примеров исходных строк и того, что должно из них получиться?

Comment: Вокруг `Y` не было пробелов в примере, но они почему-то "остались". Про лишние `>` тоже ничего не сказано

Comment: "  X >      Y    >" ----->      "X > Y"

Comment: Задавайте новый вопрос с однозначным условием, а не меняйте смысл старого, когда уже дали ответы

Comment: @EgorChernishov, меняя смысл вопроса, на который уже были даны ответы вы тем самым инвалидируете эти ответы

Answer (score 1):

воспользуйтесь `str.maketrans()` + `str.translate()`:

```
trans_tab = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(list(r'!"$%&\'*+,-./:;<=?[\\]^`{|}~') + ['\t','\n','\x0b','\x0c','\r'], ''))

res = s.translate(trans_tab)
```

---

результат:

```
In [33]: res
Out[33]: 'X >Y> I > 1Z2'
```

Comment: Можно не задавать символы вручную, а импортнуть из библиотеки ```string``` взять ```punctuation```

Comment: @Nobody, я так сначала и сделал, а потом заметил, что `>` должно остаться плюс символы `'\\t\\n\\x0b\\x0c\\r'`, от которых автор хочет избавиться, не содержаться в `string.punctuation` ;)

Comment: еще нужно чтобы вокруг  '>'  были пробелы

Comment: @EgorChernishov, советую вам открыть новый вопрос и добавить в нем побольше примеров замены. Что, например, должно получиться из `'\"X\" >'Y'!I  \t> 1Z2"` ? Всегда ли у вас слова разделены `'>'`?

Answer (score 0):

Для 3 символов из примера:

```
s = r""""X" >'Y'> I \t> 1Z2"""

print(s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', r""""'\t""")))
```

Если же 2 символа надо убрать, а `'` заменить на пробелы, то так:

```
s = r""""X" >'Y'> I \t> 1Z2"""

print(s.translate(str.maketrans("'", " ", r""""\t""")))
```

Результат 1 варианта:

> X >Y> I > 1Z2

Результат 2 варианта:

> X > Y > I > 1Z2

В общем, в первые 2 аргумента добавляйте символы, которые надо кастануть друг в друга, а в 3 — удаляемые символы